# PHP SimpleXML Parsing elements with multiple attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have to parse data from a web service that returns XML through php. I have no issues with getting the data but I am having trouble accessing a specific attribute. The xml I am parsing looks like this when I var_dump it.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["Label"]=> string(4) "11am" } ["Value"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["Y"]=> string(6) "204.68" } } }
```

To get that element I am looping through the xml and each element is like this

```
foreach($details as $key){
    foreach($key as $value){
        var_dump($value);           
    }
}
```

To access the Label part of the element I can just echo $value['Label'] but I am having trouble accessing the Y element. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Y` attribute is on the `Value` element, which is a child node underneath your current node.  That means there is a separate `SimpleXMLElement` object on `$value`.  You can access them both in your foreach loop like so:

```
foreach($details as $key){
  foreach($key as $value){
    $label = $value['Label'];
    $y = $value->Value['Y'];
  }
}
```